# Visual Studio Code issue- code won't change?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code

For  some reason the past couple of times I've tried editing my webpage in VSCS I add new code but it just doesn't do anything? An example of the issue- I'm trying to add a background color to one div element but it just isn't doing anything as shown in the screenshot.

[the HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nAvR.png)

[the CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnLfD.png)

[the result previewed in browser (it *should* have a light bue background box for the list of contact details)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAfkp.png)

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Code Studio, it made no difference. I don't want to start over from scratch and lose all the work I've done but I don't know how else to resolve this. :(

Comment: You will need yo explain in detail all your workflow, to know what is failing

Comment: Images of code are not allowed. Copy and paste it over instead.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say with such narrowed down screenshots, but you likely just haven't saved the files yet. Try saving both the HTML and CSS files and then reloading the page.

If that still doesn't update the color, do a hard refresh in the browser (This can depend on what browser you're using, but is likely Ctrl+F5)